# Adding multiple layers to Tilemill from a single sqlite DB

Tags: layers, tilemill, sqlite, spatial-index, lock

This is a repost of a question I had over at the MapBox support board. Since I wasn't having much luck over there, I'm hoping I would have better success here.

I'm having trouble adding more than a single layer from my sqlite/spatialite DB to my project.
I have already referred to the previous discussion on this topic [HERE](http://support.mapbox.com/discussions/tilemill/1862-multiple-layers-from-one-sqlite3-spatialite-file-into-tilemill) and I made sure that my layers all have unique #IDs, yet I'm still receiving an error when I try to add a layer. If I add the layer and use "Save" instead of "Save & Style" then I am able to bring the layer into my map document. However, as soon as I try to apply any styling to it will raise the error.

The error:
Sqlite Plugin: 'database idx_tl_2010_51_county10_Geometry is already in use' (C:\Users\User\Desktop\QGIS\Work Progress\Project_Regions.sqlite)
Full sql was: 'attach database 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\QGIS\Work Progress\Project_Regions.sqlite.index' as "idx_tl_2010_51_county10_Geometry"'